# How do I select siblings() of multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a `<dl>` with all the `<dd>`s hidden. Clicking on a `<dt>` toggles the `<dd>`s that follow it using the following code:

```
$(this).nextUntil('dt').toggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FZQj7/

Now, I want to automatically hide the `<dd>`s following the other `<dt>`s, so I try to grab the siblings with this code:

```
$(this).nextUntil('dt').toggle()
    .siblings().filter('dd').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FZQj7/1/

But nothing happens, because each `<dd>` I've already selected with `.nextUntil` is a sibling to each other. As a result, they're all hidden and nothing gets shown.

There must be a compact way to tell jQuery to select all the siblings EXCEPT those I've already selected, but I can't see it. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You could do it from the parent:</strike>

```
$('dt').on('click',function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').toggle().siblings("dt").not(this).nextUntil('dt').hide();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQj7/7/

Comment: Clever lateral-thinking there. Incidentally, you can shorten `.parent().find("dt")` to `siblings('dt')`, which I didn't realize before lbstr did it.

Comment: @Blazemonger It would take more than just changing those two methods to .siblings(), http://jsfiddle.net/FZQj7/13/

Comment: This is the solution I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FZQj7/14/ -- preferred over the others because of its elegance and single-line chaining.

Comment: Ah! I missed the `'dt'`. Nice.

Comment: Please add it to your answer for posterity. :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about this? Notice the use of the `not` function, [which you can read about here](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/FZQj7/6/

```
$('dt').on('click',function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $firstGroup = $this.nextUntil('dt');
    $firstGroup.toggle();
    $this.siblings('dd').not($firstGroup).hide();
});​
```

Comment: Yep, just figured that out myself. Was about to post it but you beat me to it.

Comment: @Blazemonger I do that all the time! Just a thought... Does it make sense in your case to have all of the `dd` and `dt` elements be siblings? It seems like it might make more sense syntactically to have them be grouped in their own `dl`s. And it would make this problem a lot easier to solve.

Comment: Well, I'm actually showing and hiding table rows -- I used a definition-list just for the example because it's simpler code.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to apply a class to the elements you show. On each click, you can hide the elements with this class before showing the desired set.

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQj7/11/

```
$('dt').on('click',function() {
    $('.visibledd').hide().removeClass('visibledd');
    $(this)
        .nextUntil('dt')
        .toggle()
        .addClass('visibledd');
});​
```

Comment: I like this idea, but it won't let you collapse the `dd` group by clicking on its `dt` again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something a little simpler than these others:

```
$('dt').on('click',function() {
    $(this).siblings('dd').hide();
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').show();
});
```

Comment: This won't do because then I can't hide all the `<dd>`s with a second click on the same `<dt>`.